# How to superimpose a canvas on an HTML5 video using object-fit cover?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-video

I am refactoring this code: https://github.com/idevelop/predator-vision to superimpose heatmap on a video (with any resolution and aspect-ratio).

I have the following html code:

```
<div id="videos" class="embed-responsive">
    <canvas id="heatmap" class="embed-responsive-item"></canvas>
    <video id="remote-video" autoplay muted playsinline class="embed-responsive-item"></video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#remote-video {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
    /* no letterboxing */
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transition: opacity 1s;
    width: 100%;
}

#remote-video.active {
    opacity: 1;
}

#heatmap {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
    /* no letterboxing */
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transition: opacity 1s;
    width: 100%;
}

#heatmap.active {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}

#videos {
    font-size: 0;
    /* to fix whitespace/scrollbars problem */
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 1s;
    width: 100%;
}

#videos.active {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Javascript:

I am rendering the canvas using:

```
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight,
                  0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Where canvas.width and canvas.height are initially set from video.offsetWidth and video.offsetHeight respectively.

When I render this code the canvas is not exactly superimposed on the video. I am not sure how to fix this.

Note: Canvas seems to superimpose properly if I use object-fit=fill for the video. But the video is stretched.

Comment: It seems like the actual video file is not the same resolution as your canvas. You could test that using hard-coded resolutions in your CSS - use px values instead of %. Or you can make the height dependent on the width to keep the html responsive.